# How to use props of generic list which is part of generic method - c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

in my small app I would like to reuse method used for prices calculation for few different objects, that gives me an idea it could be generic method, sometimes it will receive main-products and return them, sometimes it will receive articles and return them, sometimes it will receive category-articles and returned them.

So to avoid writing 3 almost identical methods, I was thinking about making it generic. Something like this:

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetArticlesPolicyAsync<T>(List<T> articles, Guid externalCompanyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var externalArticleIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalArticleId).ToArray();

    var externalCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalCategoryId).ToArray();

    var externalSubCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalSubCategoryId).ToArray();

    var externalBrandIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalBrandId).ToArray();

    var pricePolicyItems = new List<ExternalPricePolicyItemGetDto>().... and so on....
```

Every sigle list that I receive as a prop '`articles`' will definately contain this 4 props:

- ExternalArticleId
- ExternalCategoryId
- ExternalSubCategoryId
- ExternalBrandId

but unfortunately this is the error I am seeing:

> Error CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'ExternalArticleId'
> and no accessible extension method 'ExternalArticleId' accepting a
> first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

I am not sure if this scenario can be generic 100% ?

Any kind of help would be awesome

Thanks in advance,

Cheers

Comment: Use generic constraints to an interface that has those properties

Comment: @DanielA.White Appreciate your comment a lot! Could you help me a bit by showing how it could be done ? Anywat I'm gonna check about that terminology. Thank you Sir

Comment: Given the problem statement and the posted code I do not yet see a need to use generics. Why not use an interface (or an abstract type if you also define common behavior) instead?

Comment: @Igor I will invoke this method multiple times and in articles prop I will pass different lists of diferrent object, which I will return back once method is finished. That is whY I would like to make it generic, so it can accept every list of different objects that I am passing to

Comment: That can also be accomplished with an interface. `IEnumerable<IMyInterface> myList` would work just as well given your description. `IMyInterface` would then have those common properties you mention and would be implemented by any concrete types that you want to manipulate.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed a little more code - what does the method return? It appears that it might be returning a `List<ExternalPricePolicyItemGetDto>`, in which case that object *also* must contain all the common fields of `T article` for generics to work (or you need to modify the return value to not be `List<T>`)

Comment: @RufusL That is reason why I tried to make it generic, same list which is received in the middle of the method would be modified and returned back.

Comment: `@RufusL That is reason why I tried to make it generic, same list which is received in the middle of the method would be modified and returned back.` <- that still does not require the use of generics. You can just use an interface; `List<MyInterface>`, that is all you need. Also if you modify a list you do not need to return it unless you are creating a new list and returning that.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work with generics, the generic type must be constrained to a type that has all the properties you want to access (otherwise you only have access to members `T` as an `object` type).

One way to do this is to create an interface that defines these properties:

```
interface ExternalStuff
{
    int ExternalArticleId { get; set; }
    int ExternalCategoryId { get; set; }
    int ExternalSubCategoryId { get; set; }
    int ExternalBrandId { get; set; }
}
```

Then for all the types that implement these properties, you would need to specify that they fulfill the requirements of the new interface by adding  `: ExternalStuff` after the class definition:

```
// You shouldn't have to do anything else inside the classes since you said 
// all the types already implemented the properties defined in the interface

class Article : ExternalStuff
{
    // ...
}

class MainProduct : ExternalStuff
{
    // ...
}

class CategoryArticle : ExternalStuff
{
    // ...
}
```

And finally you need to constrain the generic type `T` to this interface by adding `where T : ExternalStuff` at the end of the method declaration, which tells the compiler that only items that implement the interface can be used, and guarantees that the properties you're accessing will be members of those objects:

```
private async Task<List<T>> GetArticlesPolicyAsync<T>(List<T> articles, 
    Guid externalCompanyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
    where T : ExternalStuff
{
    var externalArticleIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalArticleId).ToArray();
    var externalCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalCategoryId).ToArray();
    var externalSubCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalSubCategoryId).ToArray();
    var externalBrandIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalBrandId).ToArray();
    // etc...
}
```

You can read more about contraints here: [Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

What u need to do is to create an interface that holds the properties that are common for type `T` for example:

```cs
public interface IArticles
{
    int ExternalArticleId;

    int ExternalCategoryId;

    int ExternalSubCategoryId;

    int ExternalBrandId;
}
```

then define a constrain in the generic type `T` using the `where` clause.

```cs
Task<List<T>> GetArticlesPolicyAsync<T>(List<T> articles, Guid externalCompanyId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
where T : IArticles
{
    var externalArticleIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalArticleId).ToArray();

    var externalCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalCategoryId).ToArray();

    var externalSubCategoryIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalSubCategoryId).ToArray();

    var externalBrandIds = articles.Select(x => x.ExternalBrandId).ToArray();

    var pricePolicyItems = new List<ExternalPricePolicyItemGetDto>().... and so on....
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).